# Unicode space is automatically escaped and no longer recognized by `strip()`

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, scrapy, escaping

**TLDR: Scrapy escapes Unicode space code `\u0020` so it's no longer recognized by `strip()`.**

I am trying to scrape some web links using Scrapy like so:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider): 

    name = 'testSpider'
    start_urls = [<someStartUrls>]

    def parse(self, response): 
        for entry in response:
            yield {<someComplicatedXPath>.xpath('a/@href').get()}
```

Some of these links have weird formatting artifacts, e.g, they might look like `<a href="linkUrl\u0020"> Link Text </a>` or `<a href="\u0020linkUrl2"> Link Text </a>` - i.e, they have Unicode spaces in them. These spaces persist in my output:

```
linkUrl\u0020
\u0020linkUrl2
```

To at least remove leading and trailing spaces like this, I wrapped a "cleaning" function around the XPath output:

```
    <...>
    def parse(self, response): 
        for entry in response:
            yield {cleanStr(<someComplicatedXPath>.xpath('a/@href').get())} 

def cleanStr(webString): # a bit simplified 
    return webString.strip()
```

That didn't have any effect. When I looked at the representation of the strings, it became clear why:

```
def cleanStr(webString): # a bit simplified 
    print(webString)       ##### this prints "linkUrl\u0020"  #####
    print(repr(webString)) ##### this prints "linkUrl\\u0020" #####
    return webString.strip()
```

So `strip()` receives the string with an escaped backslash and no longer recognizes the Unicode code. I *assume* this escaping happens during the `get()` execution, but I'm not sure.

While it it possible to brute force replace this ex-Unicode-space, this is surely not the right way to do it. What's the best way to robustly handle these spaces inside of HTML links?

Comment: can't you replace it ? `'linkUrl\u0020'.replace('\u0020', ' ')` ? Or using `'\\u0020'` instead of `'\u0020'`.

Comment: I mentioned that - I can, of course, but is that the right way to do this? It seems like a patch on a fundamental mistake that will come back to bite. For instance, this isn't the only whitespace Unicode code - should I patch all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one char then simply use `replace()` with `'\\u0020'` or with raw prefix `r'\u0020'`

```
text = r'linkUrl\u0020'
print(text)
text = text.replace(r'\u0020', ' ')
print(text)
```

Result :

```
linkUrl\u0020
linkUrl
```

---

If you have other chars with `\u` then you can use `.encode().decode('unicode_escape')`

```
text = r'linkUrl\u0020\u0041\u0042\u0043'
print(text)
text = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(text)
```

Result:

```
linkUrl\u0020\u0041\u0042\u0043
linkUrl ABC
```

Doc: [7.2.4. Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)